# Does GoogleCloudMessaging work in China now that eveything Google is blocked?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to write an Android app for a Chinese company and it needs to support some form of push notifications. (This is for their internal use and not aimed at the general public)

I'm not too clear on how exactly GCM operates as I've never used it before. Firstly [it seems to require Google Play services](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html), which most Chinese phones don't have installed (is that correct?).

And maybe my main question: Does a GCM implementation ever require a connection to a server with the *.google.com domain? It seems that you need to implement your own server, but then there is still somehow a Google component involved?

If there are Google servers involved, then this most likely wouldn't work in China as everything Google is blocked since June 2014 (and since December even mailservers).

Can something GCM-based work in China these days?

And bonus question: If not (which I expect), what could I use instead? I've been looking into XMPP/Jabber and the nice [Smack library](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) which since version 4.1 also runs natively on Android, but XMPP also [seems to have problems on mobile devices](http://op-co.de/blog/posts/mobile_xmpp_in_2014/) and messages can get lost.

Comment: I wonder what the reason for downvotes is...?

Comment: Seems to me that you can't use GCM as most phones there don't have Play Services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825121/android-push-notifications-in-china

Comment: GCM/FCM indeed does not work in China due to the Great Firewall and because most phones lack Google Play Services. Check out
Pushy (https://pushy.me/), a standalone push notification gateway independent of GCM which can be used to deliver notifications in China. Full disclosure - I founded Pushy.

Answer (score 2):

If you say everything from Google is blocked, I really doubt you will be able to use `GCM` either. You need your own server, this server is meant to implement any logic with your clients and messages, but in order to use `GCM` you have to send a request to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` which presumably will be blocked too. A workaround could be hosting this server outside China (I don't know if this is legally possible, some countries have laws that force servers to be hosted in their country), but your clients will have to connect to the `GCM` site either way, so that wouldn't help much.

As an alternative, depending on what you want to achieve, you might try using [Redis](http://redis.io/) or even [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), although there will be probably some additional work to do on the server part, but the positive part is that you'll be independent from any third-party messaging server as you'll have to host it by yourself and implement the way it will work.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that calls to a google domain need to be made. I think that pretty much settles it.
But Redis is a kind of (simple) database, no? How is that a solution for a networking problem?

Comment: Redis or RabbitMQ work in a similar way than `GCM` in the way that it distributes messages to any subscribed client. Basically, RabbitMQ is a queue messaging system, it has several ways to work and one of them is sending the message to any subscribed client, you can also make some logic to send it to a subset of those subscribed clients, etc. Redis is **not** a queue system, but can work as a broadcast service so any message sent to it is directly forwarded to any subscribed client. The downside is that you have to implement that logic.

Answer (score 0):

In China, please use other push service, like: [pushy](https://pushy.me)

Google push does not work in Chinese mobiles.

Comment: For those, who think my answer is not valuable, please check the date on which it was posted, at that time, we didn't have options. We might have options now.